# Running background process with screen command in xshell

Tags: command-line, shell, gnu-screen

`screen` command is a nice program for us to run process background, but I found `Ctrl + a w` do not show screen windows list in xshell(Xmanager component) and `Ctrl + a k` do not kill this screen terminal for me. However `Ctrl + a d` to dettach session works! So what's wrong with `Ctrl +a w` to list sessions?

More serious, How do I know whether I am in screen window or normal bash window? Many times I try to dettach screen session, I got logout after `ctrl+a` **d**. Very embarrassing isn't it? So is there any hints to show me whether am I in a screen window or just normal tty terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting logged out when you type ^A d I'm guessing you're still holding down the control key when you're pressing d. ^A ^D is bound to "detach" as well as ^A d. For ^A k and ^A w, try letting go of the control key before pressing the k or the w.

Comment: My fault! control key shoud not be holded when `w` or `d` ispressed. thx~

Answer (score 0):

Probably the combination `^A w` is used by something with higher priority. `^A d` is probably not used by it and thus passed to `screen`. You can try setting a different command character with `-e`.

`^A d` should not log you out from a normal shell.

My advice is to always press `^A w` before `^A d` when unsure. To make it completely safe you may use the shell's key binding feature to react to it, e.g. print `this is not within screen`.

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself tricked by this. Ever since, I always add these two lines to `screenrc`:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][ %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]"
```

It changes the visual appearance of a TTY in screen. You cannot overlook it afterwards.